# Left join on a delete query

Tags: mysql

i've a problem with a mysql query..
The query is:

```
DELETE address_book.*, address_book_tags.*, address_book_tags_contacts.* from address_book, address_book_tags, address_book_tags_contacts
            LEFT JOIN address_book_tags_contacts on address_book.id = address_book_tags_contacts.contactId 
            LEFT JOIN address_book_tags on address_book_tags_contacts.tagId = address_book_tags.id
    WHERE address_book.idVitalStatistic=1;
```

The error is:

> RuntimeException' with message 'Not unique table/alias: 'address_book_tags_contacts' (1066)'

What can i do?

Comment: what actually you want to achieve by this delete query.....don't mix comma join with left join....

Answer (score 0):

You have tables address_book_tags_contacts and address_book_tags both in FROM as in a LEFT JOIN. If thats on purpose (i dont think so), you'll have to give them a unique name. But I guess you should remove these table names from the FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

**address_book_tags_contacts** needs alias, like this;)

```
DELETE address_book.*, abt1.*, abtc1.*
FROM
  address_book, address_book_tags abt1, address_book_tags_contacts abtc1
  LEFT JOIN address_book_tags_contacts abtc2 ON ...
  LEFT JOIN address_book_tags abt2 ON ...
```

[@Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6208352/steve) What do you want to delete by this query actually.

Answer (score 0):

`address_book_tags, address_book_tags_contacts` appear twice.

Remove the duplicate ones:

```
DELETE address_book.*, address_book_tags.*, address_book_tags_contacts.* 
from address_book
    LEFT JOIN address_book_tags_contacts on address_book.id = address_book_tags_contacts.contactId 
    LEFT JOIN address_book_tags on address_book_tags_contacts.tagId = address_book_tags.id
WHERE address_book.idVitalStatistic=1;
```

Comment: now queery is working with no syntax errors but the problem is that the query is not deleting anything from Tables address_book_tags and address_book_tags_contact  but only from ab

Comment: That means there is no match in abt and abtc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DELETE address_book, address_book_tags, address_book_tags_contacts from address_book
            LEFT JOIN address_book_tags_contacts on address_book.id = address_book_tags_contacts.contactId 
            LEFT JOIN address_book_tags on address_book_tags_contacts.tagId = address_book_tags.id
    WHERE address_book.idVitalStatistic=1;
```